# ModX - embedded iframe disappears

Tags: iframe, embed, modx, modx-evolution

I have a YouTube video embedded on a page in ModX. To place it, on the Page I switch TinyMCE off to reveal the HTML code then paste the iframe in. That works Ok but when I go back to edit something else in HTML mode the iframe code disappears.

Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMce is encoding some of the characters in your youtube code for you... it honestly thinks it is being helpful ;) . You have 3 options:

1. Reference the tinymce documentation, there are some options to tell it which characters not to encode. [sorry, don't remember offhand what they are]
2. turn off "rich text" on the particular resource you are trying to include the video in.
3. place your video code in a chunk & reference that chunk in your resource instead of the actual code. [probably your best bet]

Comment: +1 for sticking it in a chunk - and perhaps a Template Variable to hold just the video id :)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I tried changing the reference in the TinyMCE .js file to no avail. Unfortunately, my client likes the text editor so rich text it is. Chunk works ok but is not that user friendly...oh well will have to do!